# controller variable not pass in view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I passed a Variable from my controller back to my view:

```
public function getdata()
  {
      $data = DB::table('treatments')->pluck("Treatment_name","Treatment_id");
      return view('layout.patient-list',compact('data'));
  }
```

but when I access this data on the view page

```
@foreach($data as  $row)
    <option value="{{ $row->Treatment_name }}">{{ $row->Treatment_name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

it give error undefined variable `$data`
how can solve it

Comment: debugging tip: use `dd(data)` on controller to check what you get from the variable and make sure you are accessing the variable from the correct page.

Comment: what was the error ??

Comment: undefined variable $data

Comment: how can we debugging i dont know